# Use of paint on kitchen wall. Water and oil resistance

Tags: kitchens, paint

We are renovating our kitchen and we will not have top-level cabinets. (see picture). Now I am wondering if it is possible to use some type of paint and/or polish, for the wall behind stove or whole working area.

I don`t want it to be different from rest of the wall. It should be able to withstand water, oil and other kitchen dirt.

Kitchen is used daily, and I don`t want to redo the paintjob too often. Real-life experience with water/oil resistant paint are appreciated.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Most paint vendors in my part of the world sell paint intended for kitchens and which is described as water and grease resistant. I don't know whether that sort of paint will stand up to the kinds of heat, steam and hot grease splash exposure directly behind a stove. Most of us would want a smoke extractor above the stove/hob. If you are in the habit of thrice-daily deep-frying your [mars bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep-fried_Mars_bar) on the rearmost rings, all bets are off.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick thank you, I have seen couple of those. I am looking for some "real-life" experience, as is is one think what manufacturer writes on label, other is how does it really work.

Comment: @AdamFischer not sure of what part of the world you are in - in the USA some places require venting above the stove. As for the paint - there are many listed to be stain, oil, water and finger print resistant with easy cleaning. Sherwin Williams is a good place to look - I had some on a wall for a slide in stove and it worked just fine for several years.

Comment: I am from Europe, and venting is not required. I hand one for years and it was not used, so we went without one now. I`ll look more into the paints, thanks

Comment: A matte finish acrylic on top of any paint/finish makes it "wipe down able"